# Native Base component does not render json array map function?

Tags: json, react-native, native-base

I am loading native base component in a map function while fetching json array. I checked the json array its fetching data. I also checked the data inside map function by printing data to console, its also working. But I dont know why no native base component is rendered inside the map function?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, List, ListItem, Thumbnail, Body,Button, Text } from 'native-base';
import { Image } from 'react-native';

export default class CardSection extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Card>
                <List>
                    <ListItem>
                        <Text>FIrst list item</Text>
                    </ListItem>
                </List>
                <List>
                    {
                        this.props.data.map(albumdata => {
                            <ListItem>
                                <Text></Text>{/* not displaying in the simulator */}
                                <Text>{albumdata.title}</Text>{/* not displaying in the simulator */}
                            </ListItem>
                        })
                    }
                </List>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I know the problem, you are not returning anything from map function callback. Replace -

```
albumdata => {
  <ListItem>
   <Text></Text>{/* not displaying in the simulator */}
   <Text>{albumdata.title}</Text>{/* not displaying in the simulator */}
  </ListItem>
}
```

with

```
albumdata => {
  return (
    <ListItem>
     <Text></Text>{/* not displaying in the simulator */}
     <Text>{albumdata.title}</Text>{/* not displaying in the simulator */}
    </ListItem>
  );
}
```

Thanks please inform if this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks but I tried that after posting question but didn't work but when i removed all the native base code and used read native components it worked

Comment: > Note: List is deprecated. Use of List for dynamic list generation is discouraged.For more advanced implementation of rendering list dynamically, take a look at nativebase-tutorial. Use Flatlist instead. (https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#list-def-headref)
I like native-base, but I also use FlatList from react-native